# Files processed in mapreduce

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I am trying to determine which files were processed by a mapreduce job on AppEngine. I am using a wildcard on in a Cloud Storage bucket:

```
class FilesPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):

    def run(self):

        output_blobstore_ids = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
            "proc_files",
            "project.task.proc_files.mapper",
            "project.task.proc_files.reducer",
            "mapreduce.input_readers.FileInputReader",
            "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter"
            ,mapper_params={
              'shard_count': 4,
              'batch_size': 50,
              'files': ['/gs/project_inbox/partner*'],
              'format': 'lines'}
            ,reducer_params={
            },
            shards=4)

        yield StoreOutput(output_blobstore_ids)
```

Ideally, I would like to get the list of files that were processed by the mapreduce pipeline in the `StoreOutput` instance but anywhere would be good.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found:

## prepare the pipeline

```
files_list=self.get_files_list()
pipeline=FilesPipeline(mapper_files=files_list)
pipeline.start(queue_name='proc-files')
```

## pipeline definition

class FilesPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, mapper_files=[]):

```
    output_blobstore_ids = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
        "proc_files",
        "project.task.proc_files.mapper",
        "project.task.proc_files.reducer",
        "mapreduce.input_readers.FileInputReader",
        "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter"
        ,mapper_params={
          'shard_count': 4
          ,'batch_size': 50
          ,"files":      mapper_files
          ,'format':     'lines'}
        ,reducer_params={
        },
        shards=4)

    yield StoreOutput(output_blobstore_ids)
```

Hope this helps somebody.